# Python- I need to know if all letters in a string are contained in a list of letters

Tags: python-3.x

I need to know if all letters in a string are contained in a list of letters
eg.
string: 'hello'
list of letters: ['a','c','h','e','l','n','o']

> > True

this is my code:

```
def word(sw, lg):
    count = 0
    for i in sw:
        if i in lg:
            count +=1
    if count == len(sw):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which works.. but i wonder if it can be improved or something is missing
 thanks for the advise

Comment: `all(c in lg for c in sw)`

Comment: One small improvement you can do is, if you find that some letter from the word is not present in the list, you can return false from there itself. No need to check rest of the strings because the end result is going to be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One elegant option:

```
all(char in letters for char in word)
```